# How can we configure JNDI using tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

How can we configure JNDI using tomcat server similar to JBoss server using jboss-web.xml?
Please help me on this?

I want to know which file we need to write it? or is there any programmatic way to do this?

Thanks in Advance,
Pravin

Answer (score 12):

Write a context.xml

```
 <Context>
   <Resource name="jdbc/dbConnection" 
    auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="j<url to database>" 
    username="user" 
    password="pwdt" 
    validationQuery="select 1" 
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="120" 
    maxWait="60" 
    maxActive="20" 
    maxIdle="10" /> 
   </Context>
```

Comment: +1 for giving an example instead of just linking to the documentation at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html or http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JNDI HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) from Apache on how to configure JNDI on Tomcat 6.

- [Related topic](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a JNDI data source or something else, read the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).  They are quite detailed.